# No bytes received using pipes and execve

Tags: c, pipe, exec

I'm attempting to use pipes to send some data to child processes. After forking, I call execve, which works correctly, but I still can't receive any bytes from the pipe. I don't know what I'm missing. I tried building the same program without using execve, and it worked without any problems.

code for parent:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


char *args_0[] = {"./child.out", "", (char *)0};

struct INFO
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

pid_t child_pid;

int i, j, status;

int main()
{
    struct INFO *info;
    ssize_t num_bytes;
    char buf[30];
    int my_pipe[2];
    info = malloc(sizeof(struct INFO));
    if (pipe(my_pipe) == -1)
    {
        perror("error on pipe");
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        write(1, "fork\n", 5);
        switch (fork())
        {
        case -1:
            write(1, "Error1\n", 7);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            write(1, "forked\n", 7);
            
            
            if (execve(args_0[0], args_0, NULL) == -1)
            {
                write(1, "Error\n", 6);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    info->a = 10;
    info->b = 20;
    info->c = 30;
    close(my_pipe[0]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        write(my_pipe[1], info, sizeof(struct INFO));
    }
    close(my_pipe[1]);
    write(1, "writed\n", 7);

    /* Now let's wait for the termination of all kids */
    while ((child_pid = wait(&status)) != -1)
    {
        /*printf("PARENT: PID=%d. Got info of child with PID=%d, status=0x%04X\n", getpid(), child_pid,status);*/
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

code for child:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct INFO
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    struct INFO* info;
    ssize_t num_bytes;
    char buf[30];
    int my_pipe[2];

    if (pipe(my_pipe) == -1)
    {
        perror("error on pipe");
    };

    close(my_pipe[1]);
    num_bytes = read(my_pipe[0], info, sizeof(struct INFO));

    if (num_bytes >= 0)
    {
         bzero(buf, 30);
        snprintf(buf, 30, "num byte %ld\n",num_bytes);
        write(1, buf, 30); 

        bzero(buf, 30);
        snprintf(buf, 30, "%d %d %d\n", info->a, info->b, info->c);
        write(1, buf, 30);
    }
    
    close(my_pipe[0]);
    write(1, "pausing\n", 8);
    pause();
}
```

i should obtain

10 20 30

but i obtain

0 0 0

Comment: It seems you have misunderstood how anonymous pipes works. The pipe the child process creates is totally independent of the one the parent process have already created. Most tutorials, examples and learning material should have shown you that the pipe is *duplicated* in the child process, to be connected to the child-process standard input and output (`FILENO_STDIN` and `FILENO_STDOUT`). And for dupplex communication you need *two* pipes. Furthermore, since you have two children, you need two pipes *per child process*.

Comment: When calling any of the functions within `exec[...]` family the memory image of the current process is replaced *entirely* by that of the newly loaded executable. Any access to variables previously inherited from the parent gets lost (including the pipes – with exception of the standard streams, if I recall correctly; if these e.g. are redirected already that should remain so). If you want to pass information from parent process (e.g. the pipe ends/names) you can only do so by either command line parameters or environment variables.

Comment: Both parent and child appear pretty closely related anyway – some doubts about why you would want to separate them into two independent executables anyway.

Comment: @rslemos Indeed, it doesn't – but you lose access to anyway as the variables having stored the values previously get discarded...

Comment: There's yet another fatal problem in your code: `struct INFO* info; ... read(..., info, ...);` and where in between do you initialise `info` variable to point to some valid memory? Note that `read` won't allocate, but only use some existing buffer! In given case most simple way to solve would be `struct INFO info; /* no pointer! */; ... read(..., &info /* get address here! */, ...);`

Comment: Side note: Why wouldn't read allocate? There's no guarantee that you read all the data in the pipe at once, so you might actually need a loop, e.g. like: `size_t expected = sizeof(info) /* the non-pointer object! */; char* buffer = (char*)(&info); while (expected) { int m = read(fd, buffer, expected); if(n <= 0) { /* error handling! */ } else { buffer += n; expected -= n; } } /* now if no error occurred: use data stored in info */`

Comment: There are better means to write to FD 1, by the way, e.g. instead of `snprintf(buf, 30, "%d %d %d\n", info->a, info->b, info->c); write(1, buf, 30);` (you're writing too many bytes anyway, by the way; if this way, then better: `int n = snprintf(...); write(1, buf, n);`) simply `printf("%d, %d, %d\n", ...);` which writes to console directly – and no risk of buffer being too small on large numbers... `write(1, "fork\n", 5);` simply gets `puts("fork");`

Comment: You are relying far too much on magic numbers (e.g. 30) – what happens, if you need to change the buffer in size? Hopefully you do not forget to adjust one (or more) of all of these! Better: Have a constant (e.g. `#define BUF_SIZE 30`) or at least use the magic number just one single time on defining the buffer and afterwards rely on `sizeof` (as long as not decayed to pointer!).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is that both parent and child open two *independent* pipes that won't interfere one with another in any way. So the parent writes to a pipe that is never read while the child reads from *another* pipe that has never been written anything to.

At very first this is a consequence of a flawed design. If two processes are so closely related that they need to read from the same anonymous pipe they (usually) should be hosted in the same application (i.e. you do fork, but instead of starting another application via any function of `exec[...]` family you execute the child process directly).

An exception to this is when you want to communicate with a 3rd party application via standard IO; then you'd create *two* pipes, fork, `dup2` the respective pipe ends to the standard IO file descriptors:

```
dup2(in_pipe_in[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(out_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
```

and close all the pipe ends in the child process (the relevant ones are already duped!) while in the parent process only the two unused ones, `in_pipe[1]` and `out_pipe[0]`. Note: The naming above reflects the view of the parent (which is still going to re-use the pipes), thus the seemingly conflicting mapping of in to out and vice versa.

Actually you could use this approach in your two-applications-scenario as well, the child would use standard input/output for communication with the parent (`printf`, `scanf`, `puts` would all be usable, but also `read(STDIN_FILENO, ...)` and `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)` for binary data).

Finally if you cannot or do not want to dup the file descriptors to the standard IO (maybe you need for yet another purpose) then you need to make the child process aware of the file descriptors of the parent process. This information is still directly available after `fork`ing (you get a copy of the image of the parent process, where only the result of the call to `fork` differs), however all this information gets lost on calling any of the functions of the `exec[...]` family, where the image with the image of the current process gets replaced entirely by the one of the application to be loaded (though file descriptors remain open, which is why duping standard IO works, see above, works).

There are several ways for, including command line parameters, environment variables or temporary files – of which the first one mentioned appears the most strait forward one to me, e.g. like:

```
char* path = ...; // to the child executable
char in_fd[32];   // naming according to child
char out_fd[32];
snprintf(in_fd, sizeof(in_fd), "%d", out_pipe[0]);
snprintf(out_fd, sizeof(out_fd), "%d", in_pipe[1]);
execl(path, path, in_fd, out_fd, (char const*) NULL);
```

In the child you'd then parse the command line parameters back to integers and use these for reading from and writing to (skipping all parts related to creating an own pipe). This (incomplete) example demonstrates bi-directional communication; you need two separate pipes for each of the two directions (parent to child and child to parent) in this case; for one-directional communication you can drop the unnecessary pipe, of course.

Note that your code shows another fatal error in the child and a memory leak in the parent: In the child you define a pointer for the data (`struct INFO* info;`), but you never assign any meaningful value to it, instead you `read` to the uninitialised pointer, yielding undefined behaviour (likely programme crash, but anything else could happen as well like programme showing some unreasonable behaviour, possibly at some seemingly totally unrelated place or even – seemingly – running fine) whereas in the parent you do not `free` the memory again you `malloc`ed before. You avoid both by simply using locally allocated objects:

```
struct INFO info; // no pointer!
write(out_pipe[1], &info, sizeof(info)); // parent;
read(in_fd, &info, sizeof(info)); // child
// note how the address is taken from the object via &!
```

Final note: All code provide here is entirely untested; if you find a bug please fix yourself…